# how to write non-char* by using write() function?

Tags: c, linux, posix, system-calls

it's possible to write non-char* by using [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) function? I need to print a `unsigned long` and I have no idea how to do it. In other words, pass a `unsigned long` in `buf` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *usually* preferable to use the standard C functions where available since they're more portable. If you can, and you want to output it as *text,* you should look at `fprintf` rather than `fwrite`. The former will format it for you, the latter is meant for writing raw memory blocks.

For example:

```
int val = 42;
fprintf (fh, "%d", val); // should check return value.
```

will output the text "42".

If you *do* want to write out the binary representation, `fwrite` is the means for that:

```
int val = 42;
fwrite (&val, sizeof (val), 1, fh); // should check return value.
```

That will write out the binary representation so that the bytes `0`, `0`, `0` and `42` are written to the file (depending on what the memory layout is for an `int` variable of course - it may vary depending on the implementation).

---

That's if you're able to use file handles rather than descriptors, otherwise the `f*` functions are no good for you. There may be valid reasons why you want to work with the lower levels.

So, if all you have is a descriptor for `write`, you'll need to format the variable into a string first, with something like:

```
char buff[100];
sprintf (buff, "%d", val);
write (fd, buff, strlen (buff)); // should check return value.
```

That's assuming you want it as text. If you want it as a binary value, it's similar to the way we've done it above with the `fwrite`:

```
write (fd, &val, sizeof (val)); // should check return value.
```

Comment: Could you please explain why `write(fd, (char *)&val, sizeof(int));` would not produce the intended result? As in, would it not also write the binary representation, as with `fwrite` above?

Comment: @HonkyTonk, it _would_ output the binary representation. I added the bottom section as what to do if you have a file descriptor rather than a handle so I didn't feel the need to duplicate the text/binary choices, but you can still output in text or binary quite easily. I'll update the answer.